# How to disable Aria accessibility warnings in ExtJS 6

Tags: extjs

I am migrating a big ExtJS code base from ExtJS4 to ExtJS6, and the browser console if full mit warnings like

[W] Panel panel-1017 is a region section of the application, but it does not have a title. Per WAI-ARIA, all regions should have a heading element that contains region's title.

How can I disable those warnings ? (I know accessbility is good, but I'd like to tackle after fixing the migration bugs )

I tried

```
Ext.enableAria = false;
Ext.enableAriaButtons = false;
Ext.enablePanels = false;
```

to no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `Ext.enableAriaPanels`, not `Ext.enablePanels`.

And it should work, because, if you look into the Ext code:

```
if (Ext.enableAriaPanels && me.ariaRole === 'region' && !title) {
    Ext.log.warn("Panel " + me.id + " is a region section of the application, " +
                 "but it does not have a title. Per WAI-ARIA, all regions " +
                 "should have a heading element that contains region's title.");
}
```

If it doesn't work, you're setting the value too late.

Comment: Thx, Problem was indeed I was setting this too late

Comment: So then where to set it? I am setting Ext.ariaWarn = Ext.emptyFunc (as suggested by the doc) in launch method of Ext.Application definition, and it is not having any effect.

Comment: As you can see in the Ext code I posted, `Ext.ariaWarn` does not have any impact on these messages, at least in ExtJS 6.2.1 classic.

Comment: I also set Ext.enableAriaPanels = false in the launch function of Ext.Application definition in app.js. No effect. Even this is too late??

Comment: I added an extra script tag in index.html containing         Ext.enableAriaPanels = false;
        Ext.enableAria = false;
        Ext.ariaWarn = Ext.emptyFn;

and that works. Is that the right/only place to put this then?

Comment: @shikhanshu I have set it in application.init method.

Comment: @Alexander - Yes, init worked. Cleaner than putting in index.html. Thank you!